# MVC App with Areas missing area in route on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using areas in my MVC app.  I navigate to my CRUD form page:

```
/myarea/mycontroller/myaction/myid
```

The form contains the correct data from my viewmodel.  My form is setup to post in the following manner:

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm(
    "Default", 
    new { controller = "mycontroller", action = "myaction" }, FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    ... form data
}
```

The form posts to my controller:

```
    // GET: /myarea/mycontroller/myaction/myid
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel model)
    {
        model.Save();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("list", "mycontroller", new { area = "myarea" });
        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

The data from my view model is saved to my database.

However, when my ModelState is not valid and the View is returned to the original page, the route in the url is missing the Area:

```
/mycontroller/myaction/myid
```

Am I missing something in my MVC setup?  Why does "return View(model);" take me to the wrong route when my route is in an Area?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue.  Instead of using:

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm(
    "Default", 
    new { controller = "mycontroller", action = "myaction" }, FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    ... form data
}
```

I am using:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("myaction", "mycontroller", new { area="myarea" }))
{
    ... form data
}
```